# Unwanted white borders around transparent material

Tags: materials

I wanted to make a halo effect around a light source using a transparent object with an emissive volume. To make this as realistic as possible it needs a razor-sharp edge, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

This gives the following effect (notice the halo around the lamps). This is exactly how I want it. However, I need those white circles gone.

[image]

Is there any way to remove those circles? Or is there a built-in feature to make halos?

Comment: Why not make this in post production in the compositor like it is commonly done? Also why that funky "vortex" shape? Sounds like overkill

Comment: I do not think emission is a volumetric shader, it may be giving you a certain result but I don't think it was designed for that.  Better maybe to use a volume scatter shader into the volume input and no shader into the surface?  Worth a try, see if it meets your needs.

Comment: The two widely accepted methods to do this efficiently are a) texture cards/billboards and b) do it in compositing

Comment: If what you want is realism, make the emitters in the shape of the light bulbs, place them inside the lamps and then use volume scattering on the world or on a box that surrounds the scene. That way the emission and scattering will behave like they do in the real world.

Comment: Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question using the [edit] link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png).